# В каком месте лучше задавать отступ?

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть такой вот макет:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Нужно задать отступ этим кнопка слева и справа, чтобы они были на каком-то определенном расстояние от краев экрана.

Задать этот отступ можно такими способами:

1. Задавая marginLeft(Right) у LinearLayout
2. Задавая paddingLeft(Right) у LinearLayout
3. Задавая marginLeft(Right) у Button'ов

**Вопрос:**

Какой из этих способов будет самый грамотный и есть ли вообще разница ?

Comment: а вот разницу Вы как раз ощутите при необходимости добавить какой нибудь `backgroud` к корневому элементу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть разница, иначе они не имели бы разное название. Самый простой способ запомнить(imho) это понять, что padding отступы внутри элемента, а margin это отступы снаружи.

В вашем случае для того, чтоб сделать одинаковые отступы от всех "краев экрана", необходимо в вашем корневом layout-е, прописать всего одну строчку:

```
android:padding="16dp"
```

Принципиальной разницы не будет.

Comment: Что такое паддинг и марджин знаю ) Суть вопроса больше в том имеет ли разницу использовать марджин или паддинг ? Я и так и так получу нужный мне результат.

Comment: Если вы знаете, зачем спрашивайте? и делайте ошибки в вопросе.
В пункте 4 вы не делаете отступ от края layout, а изменяете положения элементов внутри кнопки, те текста. А так как у вас стоит wrapContent то кнопочка ваша будет растягиваться. Я же стараюсь помочь, а Вы даже не вникаете в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос поправил.